# When using MTurk with AWS billing activated is there any way to place a cap on how much money can be spent within some specified timeframe (eg 1 day)?

Tags: mturk

When using MTurk with AWS billing activated, is there any way to place a cap on how much money can be spent within some specified timeframe (e.g., 1 day/week/month)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently no solution to place a cap on how much money can be spent within some specified timeframe (e.g., 1 day/week/month) when using MTurk with AWS billing activated.

Answer by  [Phrogster](https://www.reddit.com/user/Phrogster) on [Reddit](https://redd.it/gqhyrc):

> Here's what I found: https://www.mturk.com/help
>
> It doesn't really say that you can place a spending cap on the account. The thing is, if you post a HIT, you have to be able to pay the workers, so it looks like it's a matter of limiting the number of HITs you post or limit the amount you spend on a HIT.
>
> If you don't approve HITs and authorize payment within 30 days, they are automatically paid. If you put a spending cap on your AWS billing and there isn't enough to pay for the HITs, that would cause problems with MTurk.